# Cannot import mplCandyMachine() from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, candy-machine-v3, candymachine

The imports mentioned in the docs for the JS library are not valid.

Following this guide:  https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/getting-started, I get the error that 'mplCandyMachine() is not a function' when implementing the following code:

```
import { createUmi } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults';
import { mplCandyMachine } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine';

const umi = createUmi('https://my.rpc.url').use(mplCandyMachine());
```

This occurs whether or not I use the `@latest` tag.

A similar issue occurs when importing TokenStandard from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata`, although this can be resolved by simply removing the package and then re-installing without using any version tag (`yarn remove @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata && yarn add @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata`).

Comment: I have the same issue. For me it also says createUmi() expects 0 arguments, yet an endpoint is provided in example...

Comment: Just to confirm are you using `@alpha` or `@latest` for `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine`?

Comment: @sohrab I had tried using both - attempted to use `@latest` after I failed to get it working with `@alpha`. Might have been updates since I made this question, though.